# double menu in mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

a double menu is generated on the start page in the mobile view (WordPress). How can I hide the menu that is displayed twice? I tried :nth-child(3) display: none but it didn't work.

[image]

it is displayed correctly on the undersides

my assumption is that he recognizes the navigation once in the page.php and once in the index.php where the header php is integrated. because it is displayed correctly on the underside

Comment: If you can't remove the `<a>` from the DOM or prevent it from getting there in the first place. You could select it like `.navPanelToggle:last-child` or use an [adjacent sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) combinator and then hide it how you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

You should fix that other way and see why it's generating twice, not using CSS.

But if you want this way you can try:

```
#navPanel1 + #navPanel1 { display: none; }
```